# Smartwatch support eSim but Smartphone don't support

Tags: firebase-authentication

If my smartwatch supports eSIM but my smartphone does not support eSIM, then can I receive smartwatch calls from my connected smartphone?

Answer (score 0):

If the carrier supports activating eSIM on your wearables, then  you can pair your watch to the phone and activate eSIM on your watch.

Once the eSIM activation is successfull, then you will be able to recieve/make calls from your wearable.